# Print 'and' in where condition sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, operator-keyword

I have two tables in MSSQL. Table2 has columns like Tcode(varchar) like ('1,2,3'), CCode(varchar) like ('45,2,35'), visitdate(datetime). visitdate is common in both.

Table1 have varchar commaseperated codes.

Table2 have column type as Int/SmallInt.
From table1 I have declared required variables.

Here's the script:

```
declare @condition varchar(10)-- returns ('1,2,3')
declare @cdatetime datetime
declare @Ccodes varchar(500)
declare @Tcodes varchar(500)-- returns ('1,2,3')
----------------------------------------------
 Here @condition returns 'And' or 'Or' strings 
--------------------------------------------------
Table1:
select @cdatetime=Startdatetime,@Ccodes= Ccode, @condition=condition,@Tcodes=Tcode 
from Table1

Table2:
select sum(rate)  from table2 where visitdate>=@cdatetime 
and Tcode in (@TCodes) 'PRINT @condition' Ccode in (@Ccodes))
```

Here based on @condition variable I have to print the logical operator.

Is there a way to print keyword in SQL.I'm using Visual studio BI integration services(T-sql query window).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could either use dynamic SQL to build a string and call:

[`EXECUTE sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Or just evaluate the parameter in line:

```
SELECT  SUM(rate)
FROM    table2
WHERE   visitdate >= @cdatetime
        AND ( ( Tcode IN ( @TCodes )
                AND @condition = 'AND'
                AND Ccode IN ( @Ccodes )
              )
              OR ( ( Tcode IN ( @TCodes )
                   AND @condition = 'OR'
                   OR Ccode IN ( @Ccodes )
                    )
                 )
            )
```

This is untested, but the where clause simply has a condition that deals with each option for `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: I need only one condition at a time. Query value changes when I use `'AND'` & `'OR'`. Checking condition for both would be a performance issue. its a huge table.

Comment: @InayathullahKhan SQL server would evaluate the condition in advance of running the query and only use the part of the where clause that is valid. So it would see `@condition = 'AND'`, and use that part of the WHERE clause as it knows the other side would evaluate to FALSE.  It should not affect performance in my opinion, but you'd be best to test it.